# QTableView update dynamic based on another cell Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyside6

I want to change a cell based on the value in another cell. I'm using a QTableView populated by QAbstractTableModel with a pandas dataframe.
Here is the code of Pandas Model:

```
class PandasModelEditable(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        QAbstractItemModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self._data.values)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.columns.size

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
                return unicode(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])
        return None

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            try:
                return '%s' % unicode(self._data.columns.tolist()[section])
            except (IndexError,):
                return unicode()
        elif orientation == Qt.Vertical:
            try:
                return '%s' % unicode(self._data.index.tolist()[section])
            except (IndexError,):
                return unicode()

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if index.isValid():
            self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value
            if self.data(index, Qt.DisplayRole) == value:
                self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
                return True
        return False
```

The principal dataframe (`df` in code) has this structure:

```
| Player  | O1_Score | O2_Score | O3_Score | O1_Rank | O2_Rank | O3_Rank |
| ------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
| First   | 9.66     | 10.24    | 8.52     |   2     |   1     |   3     |
| Second  | 7.45     | 11.31    | 12.56    |   3     |   2     |   1     |
```

Obviously my dataframe has more scores (83) and its respective rank, just for example

The dataframe for table (`dataframe_tp` in code) and table has exactly the same columns shown below, in GUI has this visual:

```
| Player  | Selected O | Score | FO | NO1 | SO | NO2 | TO | NO3 |
| ------- | ---------- | ----- | -- | --- | -- | --- | -- | --- |
| First   | ---------- | ----- | 1  | --- | 2  | --- | 3  | --- |
| Second  | ---------- | ----- | 1  | --- | 2  | --- | 3  | --- |
```

Where: `Selected O` means Selected Option, `FO` means First Option, `SO` means Second Option, `TO` means Third Option, `NO` means Name Option with a number to identify the above options

Based on the table above, `Score` depends on `Selected O`, `NO1` depends on `FO`, `NO2` depends on `SO`, `NO3` depends on `TO`.

Code:

```
self.squad_table = QTableView()

self.dataframe_tp = df.loc[:, ['Player']]
self.dataframe_tp["Selected O"] = '-'
self.dataframe_tp["Score"] = 0
self.dataframe_tp['FO'] = 1
self.dataframe_tp['NO1'] = '-'
self.dataframe_tp['SO'] = 2
self.dataframe_tp['NO2'] = '-'
self.dataframe_tp['TO'] = 3
self.dataframe_tp['NO3'] = '-'

model = PandasModelEditable(self.dataframe_tp)
self.squad_table.setModel(model)
self.squad_table.show()
```

And the expected output would be:

```
| Player  | Selected O | Score | FO |   NO1   | SO |    NO2   | TO |    NO3   |
| ------- | ---------- | ----- | -- | ------- | -- | -------- | -- | -------- |
| First   | O3_Score   | 8.52  | 1  | O2_Rank | 2  | O1_Rank  | 3  | O3_Rank  |
| Second  | O2_Score   | 11.31 | 1  | O3_Rank | 2  | O2_Rank  | 3  | O1_Rank  |
```

`FO`, `SO`, `TO` should traverse over ranks of every player and bring the column header.

And a modification can be change value of `Selected O`, or `FO`, or `SO` like below:

```
| Player  | Selected O | Score | FO |   NO1   | SO |    NO2   | TO |    NO3   |
| ------- | ---------- | ----- | -- | ------- | -- | -------- | -- | -------- |
| First   | O1_Score   | 9.66  | 2  | O1_Rank | 2  | O1_Rank  | 3  | O3_Rank  |
| Second  | O2_Score   | 11.31 | 1  | O3_Rank | 1  | O3_Rank  | 3  | O1_Rank  |
```

Comment: First of all, check if the value has changed *before* applying it, as checking it afterwards is pointless (since the value has already been set, the `==` comparison will not be valid if the previous value was the same as it will always pass that comparison: `dataChanged` should be emitted when the data has *actually* changed). Then, if the value changes and you need to apply that change to other cells in the same row, then *do* those changes and emit `dataChanged()` with the indexes of that row, using the first and the last column affected by that change.

Comment: @musicamante can you bring me a example of code? I'm a bit lost

Comment: Sorry, but no. If you want to deal with item models, you have to understand them. Please carefully read the [Model/View documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) in order to understand how models and views work with Qt, then reread my comment to understand how you could implement it. Most importantly, the main problem with your issue is about *logic*, not the implementation itself: if you want to apply changes to different items, *you* have to do them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first use only edit the classes as @musicamante told me implementing this code:

```
class CustomizedPandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    # Previous code hidden to clarify changes, above code is exactly the same

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        based_columns = [6, 8, 10, 12]
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            tmp = str(value)
            
            if column in based_columns:

                # If selected column in list of accepted columns to edit

                if column == 6 and tmp in self._data.columns.values.tolist():

                    # If value is in the list of headers

                    index_no = self._data.columns.get_loc(tmp) # Get index of column
                    self._data.iloc[row, column + 1] = self._data.iloc[row, index_no] # Set adjacent column as the value of that attribute
                    self._data.iloc[row, column] = tmp # Set actual cell to new value
                self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
```

Basically the only change was in class Model `def setdata` where I added a list of the index values columns(`based_columns`) for my utility, look up if the value to change was within the list of columns, get its index based on the value, and then define the next column as the value of that particular attribute based on the row of the edited cell and the column being looked up.